# PHP $_SESSION preventing or blocking website load

Tags: php, session

I have a simple page to check if the session are set or no

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['checkin'] = 'yes';
    header("Location: https://blabla.php");
    exit();
} else {
    // do something here
}


<HTM>
web page
</HTML>
```

everytime i the session is not set, i would not load the page. i have try to delete the exit() funciton, page load correctly, but i cannot redirect it to the url

EDIT :

I am forget to write session_start(); here, but in my real code, they already inputed

Comment: are you calling `session_start()` anywhere?

Comment: You can call header only if you haven't yet print nothing in the page and session_start() need to be on the first line of the page. Are you check for this?

Comment: @TheGentleman, yes i am modify my question, but in real, i already put the session_start(); on the top

Comment: @Stefino76 sorry i modify my question. now that is the real condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that you have a non-header output before the header line.
Try adding an `ob_start()` after the `session_start()`.